# How to animate clipping paths defined in SVG elements?

Tags: html, css, svg, css-animations, clip-path

I know how to animate a clip-path defined directly in CSS, but I don't understand how to do it when the clip-path is *referenced* from an SVG clipPath element.

I have been experimenting with simple clip-path animations using just CSS, until I realized you can't define a *compound-path* as a clip-path directly there, so I turned to SVG's clipPath which allows defining multiple paths. But then the *animation* doesn't work, that is, there is no smooth transition.

Here is what I'm trying...

**HTML**

```html
<svg>
    <defs>
        <clipPath id="shape--start">
            <polygon points="0,100 22.222,133.333 8.333,147.222 -13.889,113.889 -47.222,91.667 -33.333,77.778"/>
        </clipPath>
        <clipPath id="shape--end">
            <polygon points="144.444,-44.444 166.667,-11.111 152.778,2.778 130.556,-30.556 97.222,-52.778 111.111,-66.667"/>
        </clipPath>
    </defs>
</svg>
```

**CSS**

```css
@keyframes shape {
    0% { clip-path: url(#shape--start) }
    100% { clip-path: url(#shape--end) }
}
```

---

To clarify more, if I use something like

**CSS**

```css
@keyframes shape {
    0% { clip-path: polygon(-44% 5%, -14% 5%, 15% 95%, -15% 95%) }
    100% { clip-path: polygon(90% 5%, 120% 5%, 149% 95%, 119% 95%) }
}
```

it works as expected, but I would like to use SVG for the more complex compound paths.

Thanks for your time and any help in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to animate the SVG itself using [`animate`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/animate)

```css
.box {
  width:300px;
  height:200px;
  background:red;
  clip-path: url(#shape--start);
}
```

```html
<svg width=0 height=0>
    <defs>
        <clipPath id="shape--start">
            <polygon points="0,100 22.222,133.333 8.333,147.222 -13.889,113.889 -47.222,91.667 -33.333,77.778">
            <animate attributeType="XML" attributeName="points" 
            from="0,100 22.222,133.333 8.333,147.222 -13.889,113.889 -47.222,91.667 -33.333,77.778" 
            to="144.444,-44.444 166.667,-11.111 152.778,2.778 130.556,-30.556 97.222,-52.778 111.111,-66.667"
          dur="2s" repeatCount="indefinite"/>
            </polygon>
        </clipPath>
    </defs>
</svg>
<div class="box">

</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Animation option using `animateTransform`

```css
.box {
  width:300px;
  height:200px;
  background:red;
  clip-path: url(#shape--start);
}
```

```html
<svg width="0" height="0">
    <defs>
        <clipPath id="shape--start">
            <polygon points="0,100 22.222,133.333 8.333,147.222 -13.889,113.889 -47.222,91.667 -33.333,77.778">
            <animateTransform attributeType="XML" attributeName="transform" type="translate" 
            values="0,100;144.444,-44.444"
          dur="2s" repeatCount="indefinite"/>
            </polygon>
        </clipPath>
    </defs>
</svg>
<div class="box">

</div>
```

Roundtrip animation

```css
 .box {
  width:300px;
  height:200px;
  background:red;
  clip-path: url(#shape--start);
}
```

```html
<svg width="0" height="0">
    <defs>
        <clipPath id="shape--start">
            <polygon points="0,100 22.222,133.333 8.333,147.222 -13.889,113.889 -47.222,91.667 -33.333,77.778">
            <animateTransform attributeType="XML" attributeName="transform" type="translate" 
            values="0,100;144.444,-44.444;0,100"
          dur="2s" repeatCount="indefinite"/>
            </polygon>
        </clipPath>
    </defs>
</svg>
<div class="box">

</div>
```