# @keyframes animation not working with SVG clipping paths

Tags: css, css-animations, svg-animate

I hope everyone is well.

I have been trying for some days now to make the following work properly:

```css
#menu {
  /*clip-path: url(#enter-clip-path-one);*/
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  background-color:black;
  animation: Melt 5s infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes Melt {
    0% {
            clip-path: url(#enter-clip-path-one);
    }
    100% {
            clip-path: url(#enter-clip-path-two);
    }
}
```

```html
<svg class="svg-melt">
  <clipPath id="enter-clip-path-one" clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox"><path d="M0,-0.003 C0.042,-0.242,0.083,-0.361,0.125,-0.361 C0.188,-0.361,0.18,0.004,0.25,-0.003 C0.32,-0.011,0.313,-0.987,0.375,-0.987 C0.438,-0.987,0.436,-0.127,0.5,-0.003 C0.564,0.12,0.564,-0.514,0.625,-0.523 C0.686,-0.533,0.689,0.044,0.752,-0.003 C0.816,-0.051,0.811,-0.719,0.873,-0.719 C0.914,-0.719,0.956,-0.481,1,-0.003 L1,-0.984 L0,-0.984 L0,-0.003"></path></clipPath>
</svg>

<svg class="svg-melt">
  <clipPath id="enter-clip-path-two" clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox"><path d="M0,0.653 C0.042,0.885,0.083,1,0.125,1 C0.188,1,0.18,0.756,0.25,0.755 C0.32,0.754,0.313,0.929,0.375,0.929 C0.438,0.929,0.436,0.68,0.5,0.694 C0.564,0.708,0.564,0.983,0.625,0.982 C0.686,0.981,0.689,0.781,0.752,0.776 C0.816,0.77,0.811,0.96,0.873,0.96 C0.914,0.96,0.956,0.857,1,0.653 L1,0 L0,0 L0,0.653"></path></clipPath>
</svg>

<div id="menu"></div>
```

FYI, I have taken the initial code from the following URL for my clip paths:

https://css-tricks.com/animating-with-clip-path/#aa-melt

And then used the following tool to Convert SVG absolute clip-path to relative

https://yoksel.github.io/relative-clip-path/

The above code I inserted can also be played at the following CODEPEN of mine:

https://codepen.io/toulip/pen/XWypJxR

Can anyone know why there is no animation and just images across the @keyframes steps?

Thanks in advance,

George.

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58496167/how-to-animate-clipping-paths-defined-in-svg-elements [Basically, move the animation into the SVG]

Comment: Hello @AHaworth, unfortunately that did not work for me. Same result no animation.